# Find duplicate sql record

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a database table in vbulletin, where a table has just 2 columns:

Col 1 : userid
Col 2 : relationid

Col1 may have multiple entries, like:

```
userid   relationid
1           A   
1           B    
1           C    
2           B   
2           T
```

I would like to extract a csv or just manage to order them, so i could end up with some thing like this:

```
userid   entries
1           100   
2           12    
3           44   
4           33  
5           33
```

Where userid is the repeating number in col1, and entries is how many times the userid is repeating itself.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(userid) FROM TableName GROUP BY userid;
```

This query will return `userid` and a count of all `userid`s from `TableName`. Because we are using `COUNT`, we also must `GROUP BY` any additional columns we are selecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
select userid, count(*) as entries from table group by userid
```